# How to AVG integer value in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have some problem to solved an error in my program. I tried to AVG an integer column, but getting an error when the avg is 0.something,,,
example, I have a data:

```
Varchar1  |  Varchar2 | Value
1401_1   | 1401_1_1  | 1
1401_1   | 1401_1_2  | 0
1401_1   | 1401_1_3  | 1
1401_1   | 1401_1_4  | 1
1401_1   | 1401_1_5  | 0
```

then I sum the value with group by varchar1, but getting 0 as a result, it should be 0,6.  Here is my code :

```
        Dim sqlProducts As String = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 7 [Varchar1] AS Varchar1_, AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS Display1, AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Display2] FROM tbl_table GROUP BY [Varchar1] order by [Varchar1] DESC)x ORDER BY Varchar1_ ASC"
```

I though that I cannot get a result of decimal from integer, then I want it to display 1 whenever 0.something, so it take upper value. is it possible how to do that?

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 7 [Varchar1] AS Varchar1_, AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS Display1, AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Display2]
      FROM tbl_table
      GROUP BY [Varchar1]
      order by [Varchar1] DESC
     )x
ORDER BY Varchar1_ ASC
```

SQL Server does integer division and this applies to `AVG()` as well.  Use floating point numbers.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 7 [Varchar1] AS Varchar1_,
             AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something1' THEN cast(Value1 as float) ELSE 0 END) AS Display1,
             AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something2' THEN cast(Value1 as float) ELSE 0 END) AS [Display2]
      FROM tbl_table
      GROUP BY [Varchar1]
      order by [Varchar1] DESC
     ) x
ORDER BY Varchar1_ ASC
```

By the way, I find the `else 0` suspicious.  This replace the non-matching values with `0`.  More typically, you would want to ignore them:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 7 [Varchar1] AS Varchar1_,
             AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something1' THEN cast(Value1 as float) END) AS Display1,
             AVG(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Something2' THEN cast(Value1 as float) END) AS [Display2]
      FROM tbl_table
      GROUP BY [Varchar1]
      order by [Varchar1] DESC
     ) x
ORDER BY Varchar1_ ASC
```